# Just Cause 3 tether release problem

Tags: just-cause-3

I'm getting the prompt that I can press B to release tethers, but I can only trigger a melee attack. Is anyone else having this issue? I'm playing via Controller on Steam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to release the tethers, you need to be holding LT when you press B.